# How to get accuracy of model using keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

After fitting the model (which was running for a couple of hours), I wanted to get the accuracy with the following code:

```
train_loss=hist.history['loss']
val_loss=hist.history['val_loss']
train_acc=hist.history['acc']
val_acc=hist.history['val_acc']
xc=range(nb_epoch)
```

of the trained model, but was getting an error, which is caused by the deprecated methods I was using.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-233-081ed5e89aa4> in <module>()
      3 train_loss=hist.history['loss']
      4 val_loss=hist.history['val_loss']
----> 5 train_acc=hist.history['acc']
      6 val_acc=hist.history['val_acc']
      7 xc=range(nb_epoch)

KeyError: 'acc'
```

The code I used to fit the model before trying to read the accuracy, is the following:

```
hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
            verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))


hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, 
            verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
```

Which produces this output when running it:

```
Epoch 1/20
237/237 [==============================] - 104s 440ms/step - loss: 6.2802 - val_loss: 2.4209
    .....
    .....
    .....
Epoch 19/20
    189/189 [==============================] - 91s 480ms/step - loss: 0.0590 - val_loss: 0.2193
    Epoch 20/20
    189/189 [==============================] - 85s 451ms/step - loss: 0.0201 - val_loss: 0.2312
```

I've noticed that I was running deprecated methods & arguments.

So how can I read the accuracy and val_accuracy without having to fit again, and waiting for a couple of hours again? I tried to replace `train_acc=hist.history['acc']` with `train_acc=hist.history['accuracy']` but it didn't help.

Comment: Save your current model using [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/) and then load it and then print the accuracy by specifying the metrics.

Answer (score 32):

You probably didn't add "acc" as a metric when compiling the model.

```
model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=..., metrics=['accuracy',...])
```

You can get the metrics and loss from any data without training again with:

```
model.evaluate(X, Y)
```

Comment: Yeah, so I have to add it now, AND have to wait for another couple of hours after calling fit again? Or is there a solution to get the accuracy without having to fit again? My question was actually how I could get it without re-fitting and waiting again? :-/

Comment: Use `model.evaluate(X, Y,...)`

Comment: that gives just the loss, as there weren't any other metrics given. Tried print(model.metrics_names) and got just ['loss'] returned

Comment: The returned value of `model.evaluate` does contain loss and metrics. If it doesn't, the model wasn't compiled with metrics.

Comment: Try using this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html

Comment: Here is another solution: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html

Comment: In compile can we do `metrics=["accuracy", "roc_auc", "recall", "precision"]`?

Comment: @Edison, you can use many metrics, yes, but I'm not sure these others are accepted as strings like that. You might need to create a custom function and use that function as metric. Also, these compiled metrics are calculated by batch and averaged, so, some of them would not work very well, such as ROC/AUC and others that depend strongly on the entire data. You'd need to use some sort of callback to calculate the full metric after an epoch.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thanks. Yeah I just called all four metrics I had from the history. It was easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

1. add a metrics = ['accuracy'] when you compile the model
2. simply get the accuracy of the last epoch . hist.history.get('acc')[-1]
3. what i would do actually is use a GridSearchCV and then get the best_score_ parameter to print the best metrics

Comment: with tensflow 2.3.0, use `hist.history['accuracy'][-1]` instead of the `'acc'`

Answer (score 11):

Just tried it in `tensorflow==2.0.0`. With the following result:

Given a training call like:

```
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=100,
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

The final accuracy for the above call can be read out as follows:

```
history.history['accuracy']
```

Printing the entire dict `history.history` gives you overview of all the contained values.
You will find that all the values reported in a line such as:

```
7570/7570 [==============================] - 42s 6ms/sample - loss: 1.1612 - accuracy: 0.5715 - val_loss: 0.5541 - val_accuracy: 0.8300
```

can be read out from that dict.

For the sake of completeness, I created the model as follows:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001,
                                       beta_1=0.9,
                                       beta_2=0.999,
                                       epsilon=1e-07,
                                       amsgrad=False,
                                       name='Adam'
                                       ),
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to take the most performant model accuracy by adding callback to serialize that Model such as ModelCheckpoint and extracting required value from the history having the lowest loss:

```
best_model_accuracy = history.history['acc'][argmin(history.history['loss'])]
```